# Include log4j2.xml in jar itself

Tags: java, command-line, log4j2, executable-jar

I have a jar myjar,which uses log4j2.I have wriien the log4j configuration in log4j2.xml and it is fixed.
Iam using the command

***jar cfe myjar.jar mainClass myProgram/*.class Properties/log4j2.xml***

However if i create the jar and run ghe program,its not reading from log4j2.xml.If i place the log4j2.xml adjacent to thejar,its reading from it.But what i want is to include that file inside the jar and read from it.
This was possible when i was creating the jar from eclipse and adding the Properties folder as a source and checking the folder in order and export.
How can i do the same in command line?

Comment: `jar cfe myjar.jar mainClass myProgram/*.class -C Properties log4j2.xml` should do it. I'm hoping that your example command line does not have the *actual* values in some cases, as they look wrong

Comment: @g00se which part?i have placed the log4j2.xml inside Properties folder(since i was exporting Properties folder as source beforehand in eclipse).Also what exactly does -C  do?Thanks for replying

Comment: @g00se Tried this and its working!Thank you. I found out -C is to change to a dir and include one file

Comment: This is what your command should look more like, given proper packaging and naming: `jar cfe myjar.jar com.yourdomain.foo.MyProgram com -C Properties log4j2.xml`. `-C` tells jar to change directory